# Is it possible to schedule a report to be sent as email every month

Tags: email, reporting

I have a few reports generated and would need to send them out as emails.

Questions i have

1. Is it possible to send them as attachement?
2. Can the emails be scheduled to be sent every month?

I tried looking out for some documentation on these but couldnt find much on it. any pointers or workarounds to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is standard functionality for scheduling and emailing reports - on the report page the Run Report button is a dropdown combo - if you click the down arrow you will see an option 'Schedule Future Runs'.  If you click into that you can set up a monthly schedule and define email recipients.  Note that the recipients need to be licensed Salesforce users.

There's more information in the help at:

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=reports_schedule.htm&language=en_US&release=180.10